# Display first name upon login

Tags: php, authentication

I made an attempt on making a register/login system.

now the registering works, as it shows in the mysql table.
the logging in redirects me to the index.php, so i assume that works aswell.
but how do i display the first name on the home page when they logged in, i tried :

```
echo 'Welcome: '.$_SESSION['firstname'];
```

but when i log in it only shows the "Welcome:"

i'm using a header.php and include it to all pages. and added session_start(); at the top of it.

the variable firstname is there:

```
//Variables Assignment
$firstname = trim(strip_tags($_POST['firstname']));
$lastname = trim(strip_tags($_POST['lastname']));
$user_email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
$user_password = trim(strip_tags($_POST['passwd']));
$encrypted_md5_password = md5($user_password);
```

Login:php

```
    <?php
/*********************************************************************
* DatElite.
***********************************************************************/
session_start();
ob_start();

//Include the database connection file
include "database_connection.php";

//Check to see if the submit button has been clicked to process data
if(isset($_POST["submitted"]) && $_POST["submitted"] == "yes")
{
    //Variables Assignment
    $user_email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $user_password = trim(strip_tags($_POST['passwd']));
    $encrypted_md5_password = md5($user_password);

    $validate_user_information = mysql_query("select * from `signup_and_login_table` where `email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_email)."' and `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($encrypted_md5_password)."'");

    //Validate against empty fields
    if($user_email == "" || $user_password == "")
    {
        $error = '<br><div class="info">Sorry, all fields are required to log into your account. Thanks.</div><br>';
    }
    elseif(mysql_num_rows($validate_user_information) == 1) //Check if the information of the user are valid or not
    {
        //The submitted info of the user are valid therefore, grant the user access to the system by creating a valid session for this user and redirect this user to the welcome page
        $get_user_information = mysql_fetch_array($validate_user_information);
        $_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"] = $user_email;
        $_SESSION["USER_FULLNAME"] = strip_tags($get_user_information["firstname"].'&nbsp;'.$get_user_information["lastname"]);
        header("location: index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        //The submitted info the user are invalid therefore, display an error message on the screen to the user
        $error = '<br><div class="info">Sorry, you have provided incorrect information. Please enter correct user information to proceed. Thanks.</div><br>';
    }

}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DatElite - Login</title>




<!-- Required header file -->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">




</head>
<body>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<div class="homepageSignup">
<section class="signup">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<h2>Users Login</h2>

<div align="left" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px; margin-bottom:10px;">Please enter your email address and password below to log into your account.</div><br />

<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">Email Address:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST["email"]); ?>" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs">


<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">Your Password:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" value="" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs"></div>


<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="yes">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="" value="Login" style="margin-right:50px;" class="vpb_general_button">
<a href="signup.php" style="text-decoration:none;">Register</a>

</div>

</form>
<br clear="all"><br clear="all">
<div style="width:450px;float:left;" align="left"><?php echo $error; ?></div><br clear="all">

</div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

signup.php

```
<?php
/*********************************************************************
* DatElite.
***********************************************************************/
session_start();
ob_start();

//Include the database connection file
include "database_connection.php";

//Check to see if the submit button has been clicked to process data
if(isset($_POST["submitted"]) && $_POST["submitted"] == "yes")
{
    //Variables Assignment
    $firstname = trim(strip_tags($_POST['firstname']));
    $lastname = trim(strip_tags($_POST['lastname']));
    $user_email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $user_password = trim(strip_tags($_POST['passwd']));
    $encrypted_md5_password = md5($user_password);

    $check_for_duplicates = mysql_query("select * from `signup_and_login_table` where `email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_email)."'");

    //Validate against empty fields
    if($firstname == "" || $lastname == "" || $user_email == "" || $user_password == "")
    {
        $error = '<br><div class="info">Sorry, all fields are required to create a new account. Thanks.</div><br>';
    }
    elseif(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $user_email))
    {
        $error = '<br><div class="info">Sorry, Your email address is invalid, please enter a valid email address to proceed. Thanks.</div><br>';
    }
    else if(mysql_num_rows($check_for_duplicates) > 0) //Email address is unique within this system and must not be more than one
    {
        $error = '<br><div class="info">Sorry, your email address already exist in our database and duplicate email addresses are not allowed for security reasons.<br>Please enter a different email address to proceed or login with your existing account. Thanks.</div><br>';
    }
    else
    {
        if(mysql_query("insert into `signup_and_login_table` values('', '".mysql_real_escape_string($firstname)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($lastname)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($user_email)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($encrypted_md5_password)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string(date('d-m-Y'))."')"))
        {
            $_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"] = $user_email;
            $_SESSION["USER_FULLNAME"] = strip_tags($firstname.'&nbsp;'.$lastname);
            header("location: index.php");
        }
        else
        {
            $error = '<br><div class="info">Sorry, your account could not be created at the moment. Please try again or contact the site admin to report this error if the problem persist. Thanks.</div><br>';
        }
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DatElite - Register a new account.</title>




<!-- Required header file -->
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">





</head>
<body>
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
<!-- Code Begins -->

<div class="homepageSignup">

<section class="signup">
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<h2>Users Registration</h2>

<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">Your Firstname:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST["firstname"]); ?>" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs"></div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">


<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">Your Lastname:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST["lastname"]); ?>" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs"></div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">


<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">Email Address:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo strip_tags($_POST["email"]); ?>" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs"></div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">


<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">Desired Password:</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left"><input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" value="" class="vpb_textAreaBoxInputs"></div><br clear="all"><br clear="all">


<div style="width:115px; padding-top:10px;float:left;" align="left">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;" align="left">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="yes">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="" value="Register" style="margin-right:50px;" class="vpb_general_button">
<a href="login.php" style="text-decoration:none;" class="vpb_general_button">Allready have an account?</a>

</div>

</form>
<br clear="all"><br clear="all">
<div style="width:450px;float:left;" align="left"><?php echo $error; ?></div><br clear="all">
</section>
</div>

<!-- Code Ends -->



</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated, i can post the code if you need it.

Comment: Post your code, It may well be that the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you sure `$_SESSION['firstname']` exists or have you put session_start at the top ?

Comment: @kingjohnno added some code sou can see it.

Comment: $_SESSION['firstname'] = $firstname;

will solve your problem

Comment: the code added does not add anything to this post!! dont just past the variabkes, you need to show the code which you use for the login

Comment: @AlexeyDmitriev i tried that, look : http://d.pr/i/KIuF

Comment: //Variables Assignment
$firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'] = trim(strip_tags($_POST['firstname']));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_SESSION["firstname"] = strip_tags($get_user_information["firstname"]);
```

this needs to be added to your login.php

```
elseif(mysql_num_rows($validate_user_information) == 1)
{
  $get_user_information = mysql_fetch_array($validate_user_information);   $_SESSION["firstname"] = strip_tags($get_user_information["firstname"]);
  $_SESSION["VALID_USER_ID"] = $user_email;   $_SESSION["USER_FULLNAME"] =   strip_tags($get_user_information["firstname"].' '.$get_user_information["lastname"]);
  header("location: index.php");
}
```

Edit:
And to display it only when user is logged in, 
instead of 
`echo 'Welcome: '.$_SESSION['firstname'];`
You should use 
`if(isset($_SESSION['firstname'])) {
  echo 'Welcome: '.$_SESSION['firstname'];
}else{
  echo "Click here to Signup";
}`

Comment: This worked! and how do i make it display only when they are logged in? because now it shows "welcome:" when no one is logged in.

Comment: How do i for example show Sign Up if they are not logged in , and Welcome:firstname upon login?

Answer (score -1):

Clearly $_SESSION['firstname'] doesn't contain a displayable value - your first question should be is it being set to begin with?  Seeing your setter code would be useful, specifically the lines that fetch the value and assign it to that variable.